# Can SO show error questions seperately?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow

I often see questions that are **errors** that people encounter with specific platforms in very specific cases, on the homepage with all the other questions . Can such questions be shown in another group on the homepage? Or on another tab within it? Would you like this and would it be a real benefit?

Because I don't see the reasoning behind showing everyone "Help I'm getting XYZ Exception within XYZ instance of the PrinterDialog class in Java!!" questions. And this could apply to the other sites as well.

Comment: Isn't most of the site about solving error questions of some fashion?

Comment: I'm not talking about problems and solutions, but only specific errors or exceptions that askers encounter, that would not typically help anyone else.

Answer (score 6):

Ideally, the tagging mechanism should be able to handle this, but looking for say, <kbd>error</kbd>, <kbd>exception</kbd> might just as easily find subjective questions or questions about how to generate errors and exceptions as questions asking to deal with them.

That said, you would probably have that problem with any other system you implement to try to segregate these items.  In my opinion, I don't see the utility of any additional mechanism beyond tagging for these items.

Comment: Tagging's a start. Possibly a way to tag all questions with the word "error" or "exception" in the title, with the respective tag.

Comment: Any mechanism for sorting questions, such as tagging, has the problem that it is essentially opt-in, and it relies on conscientious users and diligent editors to be of any use at all.  I don't think introducing automation would necessarily help the situation, in particular it would be susceptible to the exact problem I outline above.